# Class constructor called once while resizing vector in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to learn about vectors in C++ STL...

I have a class `temp` as :

```
class temp
{
private :
    int a;
public :
    //temp() {}
    temp(int a)
    {
        std::cout<<"ctor called"<<std::endl;
        this->a=a;
    }
    void setA(int a)
    {
        this->a=a;
    }
    int getA()
    {
        return a;
    }
};
```

Now, in main, I wrote :

```
int main() {
    vector<temp> v;
    v.resize(7,temp(5));
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++) {
        v[i].setA(i);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<7;i++) {
        cout<<v[i].getA()<<"\t";
    }
}
```

The output I got is

```
ctor called
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I wonder why was the constructor called only once even while creating 7 different objects of class temp ?

Answer (score 7):

Because the elements of the vector are initialized by **copying** the parameter. The creation of the parameter you pass is the only time in your code that the ctor you wrote is called. The ctor from `std::vector` you are calling is described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), it's version (2) you are calling.

Add the copy-ctor to your class to see what is happening:

```
temp(const temp& t)
{
    std::cout<<"copy-ctor called"<<std::endl;
    this->a = t->a;
}
```

In your code, the compiler generated a copy-ctor for you but obviously without debug output, so you couldn't see it.

Answer (score 5):

The constructor is being called for the temporary object you create with `temp(5)`. All of the elements of the vector are constructed by copying that object. This will of course use the copy/move constructor instead.

Basically, the constructor of `vector` that you're invoking only requires that the type of the elements is `CopyInsertable` into that vector. This means that the following must be okay:

```
allocator_traits<A>::construct(a, p, v);
```

where `A` is the allocator type, `a` is the allocator object, `p` is a pointer to already allocated memory and `v` is the object to construct from. This will essentially use placement-new to construct an element of the vector, passing the value of `v` to its constructor. In this case, `v` is the 2nd argument to the constructor you're passing, so it invokes the copy/move constructor.